# How can I validate my model when I have an array property?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class with an array property in MVC

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Contrato_Id { get; set; }
    public string Contrato { get; set; }
    public int Torre_Id { get; set; }
    public string Torre { get; set; }
    public SkillsATB[] Skills { get; set; }
}
```

When I do the POST via jquery ajax my ModelState validation is always false

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    var _current = _Service.Insert(current);
    return Json(new { result = "success", resultValue = "" });
 }
```

[debuggin image here here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjhOk.png)

The property SkillsATB is ok, it has elements, but I think I am missing something for that array.

```
function ConvertToSkillsObject(id, name) {
    var skill = {
        Id: Math.round(id),
        Nombre: name,
        Descripcion: "",
        Activo: "1",
        Asignada: 1
    }

    return skill;
}

function GetSkillsAsignados() {
    var asignados = [];

    $("#sortable2").children().each(function () {
        var item = ConvertToSkillsObject($(this).attr("data-id"), $(this).html())
        asignados.push(item);
    });

    return asignados;
}
var MyClass= {        
        Correo: $('#correo').val(),
        CorreoLider: $('#correoLider').val(),
        CorreoLiderBSD: $('#correoLiderBSD').val(),
        FechaNacio: $('#fechaNacio').val(),
        Contrato_Id: $('#contrato_Id').val(),
        Torre_Id: $('#torre_Id').val(),
        Skills: GetSkillsAsignados()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "../../MyController/Save",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(MyClass),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (e) {
... //more javascript
```

Comment: You just want to validate whether there is at least one item in the array or individual property values of each item ? If the latter, which properties you want to validate ? How does your form looks like ?

Comment: it doesn't matter if the array is empty or full, with one item or with nullable values. @Shyju

Comment: What do you want to validate then ?

Comment: could you please post code for view?

Comment: what i want to know is why without the SkillsATB property the ModelState is valid true??? and why with it is false?? how can i bypass that??

Comment: are you sure `Contrato_Id ` and `Torre_Id ` have value?

Comment: what are the model errors? code for getting the errors: `var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);`

Comment: and how about `SkillsATB` class? post its definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was in a datepicker CSS, something was wrong in the format date. Nothing to do with the prior before

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property from the model before validating: `ModelState.Remove("Skills");`